# Qlik Sense - Displaying data labels on Stacked bar chart

Tags: qliksense

The data labels in stacked bar chart in Qlik Sense does not work properly.
When we turned it ON, instead of displaying labels for individual stack it only displays one data label at the top. 
[image: Qlik Sense Stacked bar chart with "Value labels" turned ON]

Please can any one suggest if it is possible to display labels for all the items in the Stacked bar?

Comment: If you had a label on each segment of the bar you would not be able to read it. I suggest you review how to best present your data.

Comment: This would make sense in this case ; but if I have a graph that would be readable with the values on each segment, I should be able to show that. 
Readability is not the developper's problem, it's mine.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this. You can only display the total. This is due to readability issues.

Comment: This is a terrible way of thinking on the developper's part. They should make it possible ; the readability issues is my problem, not theirs.